# Prototype Form.serialize(this) merging with another hash

Tags: prototypejs

I'm trying to merge a form hash with another hash using Prototype (1.6.0.3)

This doesn't pass any parameters to the server

```
<a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Request('/users', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:$H(Form.serialize(this, true)).merge({order: 'descend_by_created_by'})}); return false;">Name</a>
```

but this does

```
<a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Request('/users', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters: Form.serialize(this, true)}); return false;">Name</a>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I don't get any javascript errors.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an issue with the old version of the Prototype docs:

> That's a documentation issue. Expected
>   output (*from Form.serialize*) is a
>   vanilla JS object, not a hash https://groups.google.com/group/prototype-core/browse_thread/thread/d686de54683b206c?pli=1

**UPDATE**

You can achieve what you want like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Request('/users', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters: Object.extend(Form.serialize(true), {order: 'descend_by_created_by'})}); return false;">Name</a>
```

This makes use of [Object.extend](http://prototypejs.org/api/object/extend):

```
Object.extend(Form.serialize(true), {order: 'descend_by_created_by'})
```

Comment: Is there another way to solve my problem by inserting it into the object?